# PYTHON - Uppercase and Lowercase

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-idle

In my code it is;

```
If 'Laia' in name:
```

But how do I make it so even if they input; LaIa or laiA. No matter what case(upper or lower) it reads as the same thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest you convert all input to lowercase using the [.lower()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.lower) function, and compare the input with a lowercase string: `'laia'` like so

```
name = raw_input('What is the name? ').lower()
if name == 'laia':
    # do stuff
```